# How to replace " (double quote) with space or remove space?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It's a very simple and basic question that remove double quotes in python, I couldn't get it.

```
print text
"'abc' : 'xyz'"
```

I want it to display as below

```
'abc' : 'xyz'
```

tried many ways but didn't get the required way

```
text.replace("\""," "); # but it display as it is.
```

Could someone tell me to correct syntax?

Comment: `text.replace("\""," ")` - did you do anything with the return value of that method call?

Comment: In interpreter shell, typing `text` or `str(text)`will display enclosing double quotes. Typing `print(text)` will not have the double quotes. I am surprised that you get the double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i just released that print statement ignore the double quotes and gives the requires output.

Answer (score 3):

There's even better `str` method for this:

```
>>> print text.strip('"')
```

Or, if you want to make `strip` effect permanent:

```
>>> text = text.strip('"')
>>> print text
```

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method does not modify the string in place, but it returns the new value. So you can try

```
text = text.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how `text` was defined.  Consider:

```
>>> text = "'abc' : 'xyz'"
>>> print text
'abc' : 'xyz'
```

That prints as you want.  So, maybe you defined `text` like this:

```
>>> text = "\"'abc' : 'xyz'\""
>>> print text
"'abc' : 'xyz'"
```

That shows the print out that you see.  To eliminate the `"`:

```
>>> print text.replace('"', '')
'abc' : 'xyz'
```